# How do I force Excel formulas to be included when using Range.Copy()

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I am trying to us Control.DoDragDrop() to drag a worksheet and drop it in another worksheet. THis is for an app that has a bunch of little XLSX doclets that you can drag/drop to place in a file. This is all done in an Excel COM API AddIn (ie not VSTO).

What I'm doing is reading in the doclet and copying it as an additional worksheet in the destination workbook. I then copy the UsedRange of that worksheet to the clipboard. Then call Clipboard.GetDataObject() for the object to pass to DoDragDrop().

I inspected the UsedRange object in the debugger and the cells are set to the formula. If I comment out the call to DoDragDrop (because on return it has cleared the clipboard), then the clipboard can do a paste that includes the formulas.

It all works great **except** the formulas are dropped and instead it is the calculated value.

How can I get it to bring the formulas across too? Using DoDragDrop (it does work using copy/paste)?